# How to Print an n-by-n Matrix with r spaces between its columns?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, nested-loops

**Print a matrix with *n* dimensions with a *r* distance between its columns. For n = 4 and r = 7 this is the output as shown below, where there are 7 spaces between every column. (Not allowed to use matrices or arrays)**

[image]

The main problem here is that I'm trying to figure out how I can generalize the positions of 1s in terms of `n`, `r` and `i`. I get stuck because there seems to be no easy way to do this, or I'm just missing it.

Is this a good approach to these kinds of problems or is there a better approach?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int n; // Dimensions
  int r; // Distance between columns

  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%i", &n); // Dimensions

  printf("Enter the distance between columns in matrix: ");
  scanf("%i", &r); // Distance


  int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Row
    for (j = 0; j < (r + 1) * n; j++) {
      if (j % r == 0) {
        if (j == r * (1 + i) && j != 0) { // For 1s
          printf("1");
        } else {
          printf("0"); // For -0s
        }
      } else {
        printf("X");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `printf("X");` with `printf(" ");`? Also, your loop logic seems very complex if all you want to do is print `1` for the leading diagonal (`i == j`) and `0` for all other elements.

Comment: `printf("%10s", "X")` prints X in a 10-character column.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `printf` format specifiers (like `%i` for decimal integer output) can take an optional *field width* parameter; thus, `printf("%8i", x);`, when `x` has the value of `1`, will print        `1` (seven preceding spaces, making a total field width of 8). Furthermore, if you specify a `*` as the field width, that width is specified as an extra argument (with the value `r + 1`, in your case) to the `printf` call, immediately preceding the argument to be printed.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> - (optional) integer value or * that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with *space* characters (by default), if
>   required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if
>   left-justified. In the case when * is used, the width is specified by
>   an additional argument of type `int`, which appears before the
>   argument to be converted and the argument supplying precision if one
>   is supplied. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with
>   the - flag specified and positive field width. (Note: This is the
>   minimum width: The value is never truncated.)

So, for your problem, assuming `r` spaces before the first column as well as between columns, and assuming you want `1` for each leading diagonal element (when row = column) and `0` for all others, the following, much simplified code will do the trick:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n; // Dimensions
    int r; // Distance between columns
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%i", &n); // Dimensions
    printf("Enter the distance between columns in matrix: ");
    scanf("%i", &r); // Distance
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Row
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // Column
            int x = (j == i) ? 1 : 0;
            printf("%*i", r + 1, x); // Field width is #spaces PLUS 1 for the digit itself
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The picture is not very good. I assume that the first column is left aligned and the distance includes the digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMatrix(int n, int d)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            printf("%*d", !!col * d + 1, row == col);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(void) {

  int n; // Dimensions
  int r; // Distance between columns

  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%i", &n); // Dimensions

  printf("Enter the distance between columns in matrix: ");
  scanf("%i", &r); // Distance
  printf("\n");

  printMatrix(n,r);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KTcvTre1E

If you are not allowed to use those "fancy" formats:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMatrix(int n, int d)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            printf("%d", row == col);
            for(int space = 0; col != n && space < d; space++)
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {

  int n; // Dimensions
  int r; // Distance between columns

  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%i", &n); // Dimensions

  printf("Enter the distance between columns in matrix: ");
  scanf("%i", &r); // Distance
  printf("\n");

  printMatrix(n,r);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y5K8h74e5

Comment: Field width should be `d+1`, or call `printMatrix` with second argument of `r+1`.

Comment: ... but I like double-bangs, so `!!col * d + 1` (assuming no spaces before first column is desired).

Comment: @AdrianMole From this picture is hard to guess. I think first column should be left-aligned and distance includes the digit

Comment: Hmm. OP says *7 spaces between every column*.

Comment: @AdrianMole right, but IMO first column is left aligned

Comment: Hey, sorry for not clarifying it before but the problem did ask that the first column is left-aligned and that there are `r` spaces before it.

Comment: @nocomment try to sort it out yourself. Very simple. 8 characters to be removed